# infinite summation of exponential functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, power-series, exponential-function

I've discovered through Wolfram Alpha that

$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}{e^{-bt}}=\frac{1}{e^b-1}$

What are the steps of derivation here? According to infinite summation of power series:

$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}p^t=\frac{1}{1-p}$,

I expected the solution to be

$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}{(e^{-b})^t}=\frac{1}{1-e^{-b}}$.

What am I getting wrong?

In extension, how do I derive

$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}{e^{-b(t-1)}}$  ?

Comment: For the last question, note that $e^{-b(t-1)}=e^be^{-bt}$, so just factor the $e^b$ out of the sum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your second formula isn't quite right: if $|p|<1$, then
$$ \sum_{t=1}^{\infty}p^t=\frac{p}{1-p}$$
Using this with $p=e^{-b}$ yields
$$ \sum_{t=1}^{\infty}e^{-bt}=\frac{e^{-b}}{1-e^{-b}}=\frac{1}{e^b-1}$$
as claimed.

Comment: perhaps the issues was one of starting at t=0 or t=1?

Comment: Yes, that is of course the issue.